# swift multiple user using core data

Tags: swift, core-data

I have an app that ask user to login and then save username to core data and then go to task page to add new task with information using core data and tableview,
but my problem is I don't know how to make each user just see his tasks.I mean when I switch to another user he can add his own tasks without displaying other users tasks.I have done the login/registration and add tasks. 
I'm new at developing apps,so any idea would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty broad question, but from a high-level standpoint you can establish a relationship (one-to-many) between a `User` entity and a `Task` entity so you can link each user to their tasks, and then when displaying tasks, use a query to fetch only those whose `user` relationship `==` the current user.